Movie from 80s or 90s about a helmet which allowed to detect non human people
I remember seeing parts of a movie in the 80s or 90s about what I think was a helmet which, when using it, would tell which people were human or not. I remember a message in the helmet telling "not human"; I think it was related to a demon or something.
It was similar to "They Live" but no glasses, this was a helmet and it was adding a message on it.

I remember that one. It wasn't just a helmet but a fully fledged hazmat type suit. In addition to "human" and "not human", the HUD also displayed "benign" and "malign". The demon used a female form. Maybe I can dig it up somewhere.

I'm pretty sure that we had this one as a question before. Poking around...

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Upvoted for the fact that you preemptively headed off fifty million people thinking you might have misremembered They Live as having a helmet instead of glasses.

Is this Invitation to Hell (1984)...?
From TV Tropes:

Invitation To Hell is a 1984 American horror movie for television by Wes Craven.
Tech engineer Matt Winslow (Robert Urich) has moved to a new town due to a lucrative job offer along with his family: wife Patricia 'Pat' Winslow (Joanna Cassidy) and his children Chrissy (Soleil Moon Frye) and Robbie (Barret Oliver). After settling in, various people in his social circle start pressuring him to join the Steaming Springs Country Club, which is run by one Jessica Jones (Susan Lucci), who is not quite what she seems...

The protagonist, Matt Winslow, works for a tech company developing a new type of spacesuit with a helmet that can scan the environment. In particular, it can distinguish between humans and non-humans, and presents this information on an on-screen display within the helmet. The antagonists in the film are identified as "non-humans" but are actually demons.





Ah, and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/271706/23243 has it as an unaccepted answer.

I believe that it is streaming on Tubi. I watched it again a few months ago.

You can also scroll through 1001 pictures on IMDB and feel like you've watched it: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087480/mediaindex/

Yes, that was it, tks a lot !
